# Can’t seem to solder vertical plug mount USB C connector

Tags: pcb, soldering

I’m trying to re-mount a vertical style USB C connector, but I can’t seem to make a strong physical connection. After soldering, the connector comes off fairly easily.

Upon closer inspection, there seems to be some silver-colored metal on the copper mount points that doesn’t appear to be solder (I tried melting it and nothing happened). I’m not sure if it’s safe to scrape off, but willing to try.

[image: Mounting point for vertical thunderbolt 3 connector]

But before I do that, I’m wondering if there’s a better way that I’m not familiar with, such as some kind of adhesive? When I inspect the other three functional ports, it doesn’t really look like solder was originally used (also, the metal plugs aren’t long enough to reach the other side, so there’s no solder on the other end either, as you can see with the two sets of four copper holes in a square pattern).

[image: Backside of pcb depicting mounting point for vertical thunderbolt 3 connector]

This is for an LG 27MD5KA for anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: Using a soldering iron to rework a multi-layer PCB with large copper areas like that is a challenge, because the big copper areas rapidly diffuse the soldering iron's heat away from the work area. That leads to mechanically weak "cold" solder joints. RoHS compliant lead-free solder also makes it difficult. When the board was built they used either wave soldering or IR reflow to heat the entire board, soldering all components at once. What you need to do is keep the soldering iron on the grounds for 20-30-40 seconds, until the solder flows right.

Comment: Preheating the board will help, if you have a way to do that.  Any components that have been reflowed at manufacture will be fine, best not to heat electrolytic over  80-100C.

Comment: Heat, flux and patience. And good tools. Eventually, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soldering this type of connector on a PCB is delicate and patience-intensive work. I recommend the following: Use liquid Flux, there is also the option in paste, but I consider the liquid version to be more effective, apply a little flux on all the pads, take care that it does not spread throughout the entire board. Use a solder wick to clean each pad from the USB connector. After cleaning each pad carefully, take your soldering iron with the finest tip and proceed to place a little tin on each pad, I usually place the tip of the soldering iron at about 340ºC on each pad for one or two seconds and place the tin right on top so that it sticks quickly to the pad, doing this with each pad ensures that you can solder its connector. After doing all of the above, place the USB connector on the pads and the fixing holes, with a clamp you must hold the USB connector while using the heat gun of your soldering station, use between 340ºC to 360ºC for hot air while doing circles under the usb connector area, this should be done for the amount of time needed. If you can place your PCB on an electronic board support it would be the best possible option, it will probably not work on the first try, but on a third try it should work. I have soldered such connectors and they almost always take half an hour to an hour when. Patience is the key in this job.

Comment: I would like to add that if you have an IR preheater plate this can be of use here when using hot air. Alternatively, doing it by hand with a soldering iron use as large a tip as possible, a high temperature (but not high enough to lift pads) and maximum flux.... The USB shield sucks all the heat out otherwise.

Comment: @Everq This is going to sound really newbie, but just to be clear, I do need to solder the actual data connect pins as well as the mechanical support pads? I ask because I couldn't see any on the other three USB connectors nor on the loose (and now removed) one, but it could be because only very little was used, and I don't have a magnifying glass yet.

Comment: I found what seems to be the datasheet for an equivalent connector here: https://www.farnell.com/cad/3169397.pdf -- it does certainly look like the mechanical support tabs are also the ground connection for the shell of the connector, and would definitely want to be soldered if so.

Answer (score 1):

You should use flux and low melt solder alloy to make life easy for yourself.  Add flux and solder first, clean excess with braid, and then apply hot air to finally solder the connector in place.

Low melt solder is expensive, but you need a very small quantity. Do not use lead free solder as is a high melting point unless you really care about being rohs compliant.